# python csv dictwriter omits first column

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script to select only specific columns from CSV file.
I am using DictWriter to do this.
While it works fine for most occasions, it behaves strangely at times.
The output file omits the first column in the input even though I have included it in the field names argument. This happens with specific files, for some files i get all columns mentioned in field names in output, for some it omits the first columns. I am new to python and clueless why is it omitting first column at times.
I tried to print the record before writing it and I see the column with value there, but it is missing in the output file.

```
with open("F:\\TESTpy\\testin2.csv","rt",encoding='utf-8') as infile, open("F:\\TESTpy\\out.csv", "w", newline="",encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile,delimiter=',')
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=['CardNumber'],extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        print ('rrrrrr')
        print(row)
        w.writerow(row)
```

Here is what my input file looks like

[image: Here is what my input file looks like]

This is my output, cardnumber is blank.
[image: This is my output, cardnumber is blank.]

Adding the input file here in text form. Data till Approval_Code are headers  then there is a CRLF and after that is data record.

> CardNumber,BookletNumber,Merchant_Name,Outlet,MERCHANTOUTLETCODE,MERCHANTOUTLETTYPE,ERPCODE,Region,Issuer,Employee_Number,Card_Holder,First_Name,Last_Name,Mobile,Transaction_Date,Transaction_Time,Pos_Name,Initiated_By,Program_Group,CARDPROGRAMGROUPTYPENAME,Transaction_Type,Amount_Rs,Bill_Amount,Stored_Value_RsPoints,Invoice_Number,Response_Message,Reason_of_Cancel,DATEATCLIENT,PARENTCARDNUMBER,Pre_Transaction_Card_Balance,Expired_Value_RsPoints,Transaction_Mode,Adjustment_amount_Rs,Transaction_PostDate,Currency_Symbol_for_converted_Amount,MERCHANTCURRENCYCODE,Upgraded_Program_group,Currency_Converted_Amount,Tier_upgraded_On,Card_Balance_RsPoints,Expiry_Date,Reference_Number,Promotional_Value_RsPoints,Original_CardNumber_Before_Reissue,Promotional_Details,Corporate_Name,Card_Entry_Mode,Batch_Number,Request_Amount_Rs,Notes,Approval_Code
>   999999999999,678,ABOF,ABOF-Corporate,,CORPORATE,,East
>   Bangalore,ABOF,,,,,,06/06/2017,13:16:17,ABOF-02,v1,Pantaloons
>   Gold-500,Retail Gift Cards,GIFT CARD REDEEM,-100.00,,0.00,6/6/2017
>   1:16:17 PM,Merchant not authorized to accept this
>   card.,None,06/06/2017,,0.00,0.00,ONLINE,0.00,06/06/2017,,,,,,0.00,,107,,,,,Manual,2637061,0.00,{SENDERMOBILENUMBER~9999999999},

Comment: Would you please include your input file in your question, in text form, so that anyone who wishes to try out your code can do so without the need to re-enter the input data.

Comment: Hi Bill, I have added the file info in the query. Hope this gives more clarity to the question

Comment: The data you have provided is a single line. If  `999999999999` is placed onto a new line, your code works. Are you sure `CardNumber` is present in all files? i.e. not `cardnumber` or `Card Number`, it must be identical.